# Reusing a UIViewController in storyboards?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm busy design a UI for an app that I am making. The UI will have a few `UITextField` boxes where the user fills in the info. Then, they would hit next and go to another screen for additional info that is related to the first screen.

Now I wanted to approach this like so:

In storyboard have the two or three screen with `UITextField` and other small UI stuff. However these three screens share the same `viewController` class as their "job" is the same job.

Would this be a good way to go about it?

I just don't want three `viewController` classes for the same "job" that seems messy to me.

Comment: u may create a separate view using xib and present inside a view-controller make your job more clear.

Comment: So, load a different xib file inside a View controller each time I need the screen to change? I was also thinking of using view controller containment, but that doesn't sound too clean either.

Comment: not containment just create a UIView using xib then add it as subview to current ViewControllers view.

Comment: Actually, you're onto something here. :-). Using UIView will make life easier. I can just hide the view when its not needed. Add a little animation to make it look a little better and that should sort it out. Thanks! (Please post this as an answer so I can mark it)

Comment: I added my comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **UIView** with **Xib** for various form.
Then when ever necessary create corresponding **UIView** and Add it as subview to **ViewController** main view with simple animation.
When you don't need it simply remove or hide(When need in future) from the current **ViewController**.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure my solution fits you. You can create three controllers in storyboard but one controller in your code. Then you set the class type of the three controllers to the same controller of your code.

However I have never done this before. I will have three controllers if I were you.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. That's exactly what I am wanting to do. Have three UIViewControllers in the storyboard - all pointing to the same ViewController class in code.

Answer (score 1):

just call

```
[self viewWillAppear:YES];
```

and in your

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    //set the views according to your need for each case
}
```